# Flutter RichText ellipsis is shown separately

Tags: flutter, ellipsis

I'm trying to use the RichText widget with ellipsis on text overflow, but the dots are shown separated by a space of the last word, like this:

**"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and ..."**

When the correct form should be like this:

**"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and..."**

This is the code:

```
Expanded(
  child: RichText(
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    text: TextSpan(
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text "),
          TextSpan(
            text: "of the printing and typesetting industry",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
                ),
          ),
        ]),
  ),
)
```

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

not fully sure but remove the space from last

**change `"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text "` to `"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"`**

```
 Expanded(
  child: RichText(
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    text: TextSpan(
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"),
          TextSpan(
            text: "of the printing and typesetting industry",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
                ),
          ),
        ]),
  ),
)
```

i hope it helps..

Comment: did you remove space from the last??

Answer (score 0):

This space is actually space of the text. When I try your code, my result is here,

[image]

If I remove g char into typesetting, result is

[image]

So, I think its not about ellipsis or richtext. Maybe not the exact answer but maybe you can think something else.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I can't get the same result as you.
The only way that I get "typesettin..." is when I change the **and** for **a**

Comment: It is normal, because my test emulator has different size from your use. I just wanna tell you, probably its not about richtext or ellipsis